# SQL Server CE Code First migrations problems

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a bunch of problems trying to enable (code-first) migrations for my SQL Server Compact 4.0 database for my desktop .NET app.

`Enable-Migrations` does work and the directory `Migrations` is created. After that when I try to run `Add-Migration InitialMigration`, I get:

> Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name = Logo.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

This is the first problem, but I solved it by running Visual Studio as Administrator... don't like that solution and also don't know if later in production it will work without the app being run in Admin mode. I let that problem aside for now...

My connection string:

```
<add name="LogoContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Logo.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"/>`
```

So after running `Add-Migration InitialMigration` in Administrator mode I get an empty migration... that's ok. Then I delete the migration and add a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Blog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I add a reference to the context class:

```
public class LogoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Then run `Add-Migration InitialMigration` again and get:

```
public partial class InitialMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Blogs",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Content = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Blogs");
    }
}
```

After running `Update-Database` I see:

```
Applying code-based migrations: [201304211225255_InitialMigration].
Applying code-based migration: 201304211225255_InitialMigration.
Running Seed method.
```

Now the problem appears - in my Server Explorer I examine the database `Logo.sdf` and it **does not** include the table `Blogs`! I even try to run this code from my app:

```
var db = new LogoContext();
db.Posts.Add(new Blog { Title= "moo" });
db.SaveChanges();
```

to check if maybe my Server Explorer isn't showing the table.. but I get an exception:

> The specified table does not exist. [ Blogs ]

So the migrations are obviously not being applied to my `Logo.sdf` file :(

If I remove the connection string from `app.config`, the connection to a local instance of SQL Server Express is assumed. And there it works flawlessly!! When I examine the database with SQL Server Management Studio, I see the new `Blogs` table and also a system table for metadata about migrations...

Another little piece of information:

When I try to run `Update-Database` again, I get "No pending code-based migrations." and that tells me that some data is being saved to `Logo.sdf` after all... at least some metadata about migrations, but still I can't see that table in Server Explorer.

I'm using VS 2012 and EF 5.0.

Please help me understand this... It looks to me that something is seriously wrong because it just works with SQL Server Express instance, but not with SQL Server CE 4.0. :((

Thank you!
david

Comment: Suggest you start by having a full path to your database file in your connection string, my guess is you have several copies of the database file, for example in your bin/debug folder

Comment: Hmm I also thought about this, but I "made sure" VS was accessing the correct Logo.sdf by deleting the bin/Debug version... I never tested it with absolute paths because I ruled out an option that there could be a third copy of the db file somewhere... AND there it is, in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Logo.sdf" ... ok so that mystery is solved - thank you.. So do I really have to use the absolute path to the file? When I compile the solution the config file of the compiled app also contains an absolute path which is not good...?

Comment: Use a full path during Development, or better initialize the context with a connection string you construct in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was that the solution created a separate .sdf file here:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Logo.sdf"

Which was unexpected and strange IMHO...

I ended up using this connection string:

```
<add name="LogoContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Logo.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"/>
```

This references bin/Debug/Logo.sdf and it works during development and when running a .exe separately.

The only thing with this way is that my Logo.sdf project file (which was getting copied to Debug "if newer") is now completely ignored. All the migrations will be run on the Debug file.. That's probably good too....

Thanx Erik for the hint!
david

Comment: Can confirm this works for web debug with IIS Express too. In my case it tried to create to "C:\Program Files(86)\IIS Express\db.sdf"