# multiple context and multiple database in code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I want two database and two context. One for **ASP.NET MVC** based project (With **SQL Server**) and one for **windows application** based project admin management tools (With **SQL Server CE**).
my Solution structure like below:

```
MySolution
--DataAccessLayer (Class Library Project)
--ModelProject (Class Library Project)
--MyWebApplication (ASP.NET MVC Project with SQL Server)
--MyAdminTools (Windows Application Project with SQL Server CE)
```

I store POCO class files in ModelProject. Some of this POCO class was shared in two database so I create DataAccessLayerProject with two context both of them were inherited from DbContext and I set connection string in constructor like below:

```
public MyWebApplicationContext()
            : base("WebDB")
    {
    }
public AdminToolsContext()
            : base("AdminToolsDB")
    {
    }
```

and this is connection strings:

```
<add name="WebDB" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WebDB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AdminToolsDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AdminToolsDB.sdf" />
```

I also enable migration for my context step by step with [this post guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110536/ef-4-3-auto-migrations-with-multiple-dbcontexts-in-one-database/10009491#10009491)

Now I have two questions:

**First:** Is this the correct structure for store project and solution in separate project?? (context and model in separate project)

**Second:** In above steps everything is right except SQL Server CE database.
when I run update-database for my SQL Server CE context, Package Manager Console print a message that update and seeding data done successfully but **AdminToolsDB.sdf** not created in DataAccessLayer bin/Debug folder. I also search for this file in entire solution folder but no file exist. Where is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server CE Code First migrations problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131193/sql-server-ce-code-first-migrations-problems)

Comment: No I add |DataDirectory| to prevent that issue.

Comment: close solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354083/ef6-and-multiple-configurations-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact

Comment: CFM only supports on DbContext per project. Your situation may be beyond the limitations of CFM if you require the two DBs to be different.